# Java: retrieving information from a html

Tags: java, html

I am trying to getting information from a html
but I have difficulties in locating the location of data I need
For example, in this website,
http://koryaku.fullbokko.drecom.jp/u1152/

I would like to get the value in the table,
(1, 1926, 750, 403)
while the cell do not have a id,
how can I use java code to get the data?

Comment: You can parse and check for `<td class="cell_th">` to get it.

Comment: try jsoup lib : http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many 3rd party libraries that can assist you in parsing html. In the past I have used [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). It allows you to specify exactly what you are looking for by accessing tags, classes, ids and so on. It also has a good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is count the table headers:

`<table class="detail b">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="cell_m"></th>
          <th class="cell_l">Lv</th>
          <th class="cell_l">HP</th>
          <th class="cell_l">攻撃</th>
          <th class="cell_l">回復</th>
         </tr>`

Make an array, then count table headers with a variable `col` and store table headers in an array, `array[col] = "Lv"` and then you know `col` is `"Lv"` so you can count the `<td>` elements with `numberOfTds` until you get to the column you want. When `col == numberOfTds` you know you are at `array[col]` so you can grab that `<td>`